# Project not built. Build path incomplete. Repairing build path did not work

Tags: eclipse, groovy, buildpath

java version "10.0.1"
Eclipse jee 2018-2019
Windows 10

I'm just trying to add a simple file to my package. After adding the file, I get the below error.

> The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot
>   find the class file for groovy.lang.GroovyObject. Fix the build path
>   then try building this project.

Pretty much all posts say to delete the JRE System Library and add it again, do a refresh, clean restart. I did this, but I'm still getting a build path error.

I followed these instructions. Other forums on stack say similar things.
http://hemant-vikram.blogspot.com/2012/07/eclipse-build-error-project-was-not_12.html

New to Eclipse and Groovy. I just want to follow the tutorial :|

Comment: To what tutorial are you referring? Did you add something containing groovy.lang.GroovyObject to the project's Build Path?

Comment: Actually I figured it out I think. I was using the only Groovy, Geb Spock tutorial on Udemy. The lecturer is using Eclipse Mars. I'm using Jee. Creating a new file the same way he did would create a build path error. Creating a new class instead would work.

Answer (score 2):

If you have added references to Groovy types, you can add Groovy libraries to your classpath by right-clicking on your project and choosing "Add Groovy Libraries to classpath".  This assumes you have [Groovy Development Tools](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/groovy-development-tools) installed.

Or you can add "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all" through Ivy, Maven or Gradle if you are using one of those for dependency management.